# _load_data: Condition !f is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_OPEN (Godot)

Tags: godot, gdscript

I started with Godot about 2 weeks ago, But have been getting `_load_data: Condition !f is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_OPEN (Godot)` on this code:

```
extends Area2D

var points = 0
var pointAdder = 1
var pointMultiplier = 1
# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
            points = (points + pointAdder)*pointMultiplier
            get_node("../scoreLabel").text = str(points)
```

Node tree:

```
Spatial (Node)
 ├─backgroundMap :: TileMap
 └─scoreLabel :: Label
    ├─treeClickableArea :: Area2D <<
    ├─treeSprite :: Sprite
    └─treeCollider :: CollisionShape2D
```

I am trying to display the number of times that `treeCollider` has been clicked. When I launch the game despite the error, It will count up no matter where I click.

Comment: Not sure how much this helps in your case, but in almost every case I've seen before `Condition ' !f ' is true. returned: ERR_CANT_OPEN` is one of Godot's ways of saying "file not found". This is usually due to a spelling mistake (case sensitive), or a path error. First thing would be to double check both of these.  If the problem still persists, you might want to look into using an input singleton.

Comment: Quick question: I would use the name of the node, not some other ID I am unaware of, right?

Comment: Yes, when calling a node, use it's name (case sensitive). Also - instead of using `..` to navigate upwards on the node tree, try `get_parent().get_node()` or `get_tree().get_root().get_node()`

Comment: An example in you case would be `get_parent().get_node(scoreLabel).text = str(points)`

Comment: OK, let me try...

Comment: OK. Don't I need quotations around the node?

Comment: Yes you do (my bad).

Comment: Ok thanks. That works as well, but it still does not function, @ChristopherBennett. I have triple checked that there are no spelling mistakes, and there are not. Earlier, you said "mostly" not "all". What are the alternative causes?

Comment: I don't remember what the exception was.. it was a while ago, maybe eve pre-3.0. Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Might be a longshot, but try changing `func _input(event)` to `func _unhandled_input(event):`

Comment: Yes, I am gettig the same error. Let me try changing the function

Comment: nah, It didn't change anything. Same error. Thanks anyways.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't help. When I have more time, i'll take a deeper look at it and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: OK, i greatly appreciate it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Oh note: I don't know what i changed, but now when I run the script, it does not count at all. I changed nothing, and the few changes i did make i reverted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is kind of a workaround, but this WILL work (I have tested on Godot 3.2)

Keep your same node setup - final code looks like this:

```
extends Area2D

var points = 0
var pointAdder = 1
var pointMultiplier = 1
var mouseover = false

func _input(event):
    if (mouseover and event is InputEventMouseButton && event.pressed):
            points = (points + pointAdder)*pointMultiplier
            get_parent().get_node("scoreLabel").text = str(points)

func _on_Area2D_mouse_entered():
    mouseover = true

func _on_Area2D_mouse_exited():
    mouseover = false
```

As you can see from the bottom two functions, you will have to connect 2 signals to your Area2D: `mouse_entered()` and `mouse_exited()`. When it asks what node to connect to, connect to itself (choose the same Area2D).

To make this work, I've added the variable `mouseover` and set it to false. For the `mouse_entered()` signal, `mouseover` gets set to `true`. For `mouse_exited()`, it gets set to `false`. This will track whether the mouse is actually over your area before you click. When tested, the `scoreLabel` counts up when the `Area2D` is clicked on, but not when clicking anywhere else.

I know this is kind of a hackish solution - I've seen better proposed, but they don't seem to be working for this case (label counts up no matter where you click). At least this method works for sure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I think this should have worked. Although, it still does not count and gives the same error. (_load_data: Condition "!f" = true. Returned ERR_CANT_OPEN.) In case this helps, here is a screenshot:

Comment: I see you typed the code, but it looks like you didn't actually connect a signal. If you click on the Area2D node (treeClickableArea), and then look at the top of the Inspector window, you will see 2 tabs: Inspector and Node. Click the Node tab, and you will see all the signals. Double click on the one you want and follow the steps. Rinse and repeat for the other. When connected correctly, there should be a little "wi-fi" looking logo  next to your Area2D.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, in your picture, you forgot the line `points = (points + pointAdder)*pointMultiplier`.

Comment: Oh, and change `("/scoreLabel")` to just `("scoreLabel")`.

Comment: oh I was trying to see if anything was different

Comment: I need to connect a the mouse_entered() and mouse_exited() signals under the id _on_Area2D_mouse_entered and _on_Area2D_mouse_exited, correct? (I haven't ever worked with signals before :-/ )

Comment: Yeah connect the signals. When it asks where to connect, choose itself, and put the mouseover true/false under the code it provides by the signal. (ex: `func _on_Area2D_Mouse_entered()` ). Just like in the code above. As a side note, If you plan on continuing with Godot, it's well worth taking the time to learn all about signals because Godot uses them for a lot of things, and they can be tricky (a pain in the ass) to get the hang of at first.

Comment: which signals do you mean?

Comment: The ones we've been talking about. Select the node (treeClickableArea), choose the "mouse_entered()" signal in the inspector window under the node tab. When asked, connect it to itself, it will take you to the script editor and will have placed the code (if it is't already there) `func _on_Area2D_mouse_entered():`. Under that, write `mouseover = true`. Go back to the node and do the same thing with the `mouse_exited()` signal.

Comment: Y'know, it would have helped If I wasn't dumb and deeded t put the label underneath of the tilemaps. Sorry about all that. It works perfectly!

Comment: No problem. If you're just breaking into a new engine, get used to head banging moments like that. Glad it finally works for you.

Comment: I don't suppose there might be an attribute like .text so I can increase the font size too? Or would I have to make my own font?

Comment: As far as I know, Godot is pretty barren when it comes to default font options. To get extra options, such as size, you have to use dynamic fonts. You can select it from the Label node under font in the inspector, and you have to choose "new dynamic font" (bitmap is generic and limited). You have to supply your own font file though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I greatly appreciate your help through all of this